# Recursive implementation of javascript object formatter returning data in the wrong order

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to write an implementation of JSON/javascript object formatters, but for some reason my function is returning the object components in the wrong order. For example, the following object:

```
{"Crows":{"players":{"Ben":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Ty":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Pigeons":{"players":{"Bill":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tim":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Seagulls":{"players":{"Bob":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tom":{"jersey #":"2B"}}}, "bob": [1, 2, 3]}
```

when used as an argument in the function should return this:

```
{
  "Crows": {
    "players": {
      "Ben": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Ty": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Pigeons": {
    "players": {
      "Bill": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tim": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Seagulls": {
    "players": {
      "Bob": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tom": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, it's returning something like this:

```
'
'jersey #:1B',

'
'jersey #:2B',

'
Ben: {
    undefined},
'
Ty: {
    undefined},

'
players: {
    undefined},

'
'jersey #:1B',

'
'jersey #:2B',

'
Bill: {
    undefined},
'
Tim: {
    undefined},

'
players: {
    undefined},

'
'jersey #:1B',

'
'jersey #:2B',

'
Bob: {
    undefined},
'
Tom: {
    undefined},

'
players: {
    undefined},

'
Crows: {
    undefined},
'
Pigeons: {
    undefined},
'
Seagulls: {
    undefined},
```

What's incorrect about the way I'm structuring the logic that's causing this odd format?

```
function prettyPrint(data){
  var result = "";
  const indent = "    ";
  for (var key in data) {
    // console.log("key is: " + key)
    var value = data[key]
    // console.log("value is:" + value)

    if (typeof value == 'string'){
      var line = "\n" + "'" + key + ":" + value + "'";
      // console.log("line we just generated when value is a string:" + line)
      result += "'" + line + ",\n";
    }
    else if (typeof value == 'object'){
      // console.log("the value is an object")
      if (value instanceof Array){
        // console.log("value is an array")
        var line  = "\n" + "'" + key + "'" + ": " + "[ " + value + " ]";
        // console.log("line we just generated when value is an array object:" + line)
        result += "'" + line + ",\n";
      }

      else{
        // console.log("the value is an object of type dict")
        var line = "\n" + key + ": " + "{\n" + indent + prettyPrint(value) + "}";
        // console.log("line we just generated when value is a dict object:" + line)
        result += "'" + line + ",\n";
      }
    }

  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Ummm `JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)`??

Comment: @Ele returns `'{"Crows":{"players":{"Ben":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Ty":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Pigeons":{"players":{"Bill":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tim":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Seagulls":{"players":{"Bob":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tom":{"jersey #":"2B"}}}, "bob": [1, 2, 3]}'` - look at the desired output

Comment: @Ele I'm trying to write a JSON formatter manually, not using things like stringify. It's for practice purposes :)

Comment: @capncrunch how should the bob array value be printed.

Comment: You need to return the result at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get into an actual solution, let's step back and understand the kind of data we're working with and what we're trying to do. Some of this may be obvious, but perhaps other readers could benefit:

A JSON object is essentially a **Tree**. Why?

- It contains a root node (the top level object itself)
- The root node has children (the various keys belonging to the object)
- Every child has exactly one parent.
- Every child could have one more siblings.
- If the node itself is an Object (non-Array), it could have children of its own.

The task you have is to print out the tree in a specific order. In the order in which you read the object from left to right, with the appropriate indentation to designate the nesting of objects.

However if you think of the JSON object as a tree, what this means is you'll need to do a **pre-order traversal** over this object. This is because you want to do something with the node, **before** traversing a node's children, in this case, print it.

The basic algorithm is:

- Visit a node and do something
- Traverse each child in the subtree and repeat the above.

As it applies to your problem:

- Visit a node and print the key
- If the node's value is an object, iterate over each key in that object and repeat above.
- If the node's value is not an object, print the value.

While recursion is not necessary to accomplish this, it helps keep track of what level we're on, since the level will mean how far we indent.

Here's just one potential solution, doing a pre-order DFS.

Keep in mind, I'm just doing console.log outputs just to *emphasize* the different vars needed to make up a single line. I'm also not paying attention to trailing commas, how arrays are formatted, etc.  But this should give you a basic structure.

```js
var json = {"Crows":{"players":{"Ben":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Ty":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Pigeons":{"players":{"Bill":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tim":{"jersey #":"2B"}}},"Seagulls":{"players":{"Bob":{"jersey #":"1B"},"Tom":{"jersey #":"2B"}}}, "bob": [1, 2, 3]}

function prettyPrint(key, val, level) {
    // Get indentation amount
    let indent = "";
    for (let x = 0; x < level; x++) {
        indent += "  ";
    }

    // Will we need to print the key?
    let keyLabel = key ? key + ':' : '';

    // If the value is an object, traverse children pre-order
    if (typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
        console.log(indent, keyLabel, '{');
        Object.keys(val).forEach((k) => {
            prettyPrint(k, val[k], level+1)
        });
        console.log(indent, '}', ',');
    } else {
        // Otherwise just print the value
        console.log(indent, keyLabel, val, ',');
    }
}


prettyPrint(null, json, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you shouldn't rely on `for...in` loops for things where order is important. According to MDN:

> **A `for...in` loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order** (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

When you need to conserve the order of the elements, use `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` with a `for...of` or `for` loop:

```
var obj = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (let key, i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    key = keys[i];
    console.log(obj[keys]);
}
```

Alternatively, with a `for...of`:

```
for (let key of keys) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

One could also use `Object.values()`, which would list the values rather than the keys:

```
var values = Object.values(obj);

for (let value, i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log(value);
}

for (let value of values) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain why is `for...in` less reliable?